# Uploading Electron .app bundle to App Store Connect/Mac App Store

Tags: electron, mac-app-store, electron-packager

I'm using electron-packager (https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) to build my electron app and it says in the Readme it's possible to target:
macOS (also known as darwin) / Mac App Store (also known as mas)* (for x86_64 and arm64 architectures)

But the outputted file is an .App bundle but not a .pkg file. And the Transporter application to upload to app store connect doesn't allow .App files to be uploaded. So I'm wondering how are you supposed to upload the outputted .app file to app store connect / the mac app store? Is it possible to make electron-packager generate an appropriate file for Transporter?

Or otherwise what is the best way to generate the appropriate files to upload file to the mac app store?

Answer (score -1):

You can set target as pkg instead of mas